# Using CASE WHEN DATE Statement in MariaDB 10.2.15

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table

I created a query to display the `ScanIn` Field in one month on each date

Code :

```
SELECT
    Employee.Name,
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 1 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '1',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 2 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '2',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 3 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '3',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 4 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '4',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 5 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '5',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 6 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '6',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 7 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '7',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 8 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '8',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 9 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '9',
    CASE WHEN DAY(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 10 THEN LogsFormatted.ScanIn ELSE '-' END AS '10'
FROM
    HrEmployee AS Employee
    LEFT JOIN HrAttLogsFormatted AS LogsFormatted ON Employee.FingerId = LogsFormatted.FingerId
WHERE
    LogsFormatted.DateIn BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
    AND Employee.Id = 14522228
```

In Database

```
| DateIn     | ScanIn   |
| 2019-03-04 | 06:58:09 |
| 2019-03-05 | 07:34:09 |
| 2019-03-06 | 07:12:05 |
| 2019-03-08 | 06:56:51 |
```

Result From Database [Click Here](https://ibb.co/7CT2dJx)

I want the results of the query to display

```
Name    1   2   3   4         5        6         7  8         9  10
Aldan   -   -   -   06:58:09  07:34:09 07:12:05  -  06:56:51  -  -
```

But with the query I made unsuccessfully, is there a way to solve it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want [`DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day), not `DATE`

Comment: Do you want the day of month or day of week (ie. Sun, monday, etc as 0-7)?

Comment: @SloanThrasher day of month with date (date 1, 2, 3, ...)

Comment: Are you trying to pivot every day number into a column? For March, you'll end up with 31 columns plus the name column? How are you going to use this data? What about April that will only have 30 days? If you always have 31 day columns then you'll still be able to do it, but again, what is it that you're trying to do with this data?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pivoting-in-mariadb/

Comment: @Shawn I want to calculate the date of the ScanIn data set that month, I issued April with only 30 days I still asked how, but another alternative I made throughout the month with 31 days ... is there another alternative?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Aldan So you'll create a new table for each month? That will very quickly become a maintenance nightmare. Particularly in about 15 days when March becomes April. Then 31 days after that, when April becomes May...... Honestly, I would just have a single table that stores each person's login, then use a query to get the logins I need, then, like Strawberry said, use your application to format the display of that data. But I'm not familiar with your app or your data.

Comment: As a note, if you have to change your data structure or your code for common changes (like month-to-month), there will likely be a much more efficient way to handle it. Once an application is written, it should usually require as minimal hands-on maintenance as possible, if any. That will also make it significantly less error-prone and easier to interpret for the next developer who looks at it (or you in a year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT e.Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 1 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '1',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 2 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '2',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 3 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '3',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 4 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '4',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 5 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '5',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 6 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '6',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 7 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '7',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 8 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '8',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 9 THEN lf.ScanIn END) AS '9',
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(lf.DateIn) = 10 THEN lf.ScanIn END AS '10'
FROM HrEmployee e LEFT JOIN
     HrAttLogsFormatted lf
     ON e.FingerId = lf.FingerId
WHERE lf.DateIn BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31' AND
      e.Id = 14522228
GROUP BY e.name;
```

I don't recommend using a dash for missing data.  Just use `NULL` -- what SQL uses.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, This works for now but i end up with 31 columns plus the name column

Comment: @Aldan . . . Your comment is very confusing.  This query returns 11 columns and 1 row (assuming there is a match in the data), which is what your question is asking.  You can add more columns if you like, but this is all presumably what you want to do.

Comment: If expanded to 31 days, Gordon's query will just return a dash for any days not in the requested month.